# Groups and IAM roles

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-identity

The [GCP Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/docs/enterprise/best-practices-for-enterprise-organizations) doc has this statement;

> We recommend collecting users with the same responsibilities into
>   groups and assigning Cloud IAM roles to the groups rather than to
>   individual users.

I assume this refers to Cloud Identity Groups, yes?

Where do I assign Cloud IAM roles to groups?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to create a Google Group with the imported members in Cloud Identity. If you use Google Group, that group must have an email address (normally `<grou-name>@<domain>`). You can then use this email address in IAM to give access to all people in that group.

See [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/concepts/groups) for more info.

Comment: That's it.  In IAM click ADD.  In the "Add members to" fill in the New Members input box with the email address of the Identity Group.  It will not auto fill like a users email address will. Thanks for the help!!